# Split Cart for WooCommerce multi vendor

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for references on multi-vendor split woocommerce carts, is there anyone who can help me, I want the cart on woocommerce to be split according to author or store?

Like in this example:

[image]

Comment: What you want to do? Do you want to built it by own or want to purchase a plugin?
https://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-woocommerce-marketplace-split-cart-plugin/20985554

Comment: I want to make my own, do you have a reference?

Comment: Why don't you find free plugin of any paid plugin from google and download it and take a reference from it.? It will prove to be a good start.

Comment: okay thank you i will try your idea, thanks you